# How to use an omega template with hook_theme

Tags: 7, theming

I'm using page callback function to display a page. How would I change this to use an omega template? I've tried adding a vis.tpl.php to the omega templates function but to no avail. I don't understand how to declare a omega template for use with a particular page.

```
<?php

function vis_menu() {

  $items['images'] = array(
    'title' => 'Images',
    'page callback' => 'image_page',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
  );
  return $items;
}

function image_page() {
  return 'hello';
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using this question as a basis to work from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4100485/register-your-theme-functions-in-drupal.

The template (.tpl.php file) goes in the omega template directory. You then use a `hook_theme` function to define the theme with the template key in the array pointing to the name of your template file.

The theme is then called with `theme(your-theme-name)`

Here's my working example for my module called `vis`:

```
function vis_menu() {

  $items['images'] = array(
    'title' => 'Images',
    'page callback' => 'image_page',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
  );
  return $items;
}

function image_page() {
  return theme('images');
}

function vis_theme() {
  return array(
    'images' => array(
      'variables' => array(),
      'template' => 'vis',
    ),
  );
}
```